# How to propagate a CSS transform: Scale() to select option tags

Tags: html, css, navigation, transform

``
Dear all,
I am doing an HTML5 app with a navigation where you can zoom items inside an elements content.
Items in the content have some input  + tags.
To zoom the content, I use style="transform:scale(..)" on the top content element.
This works most of the time text/dev/etc.…, but the scale is not propagated for the option tags such as in the following code.
The option doesn’t keep the proportional font-size to its parent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz1om.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<style>
select
{  border-radius: 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid ;
  padding-left:5px;
  background-color:blue;}
select  option
{  background-color: red;}
</style>
<body>
<div style="transform:scale(0.5)">          
  <select>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">item1</option>
    <option value="1">item2</option>
  </select>
<div>
</body></html>
```

Where I am wrong? Any workaround for this issue?
regards

Answer (score 0):

You are not wrong.  Essentially it cannot be done.  See for example [<option> (not stylable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css).

See also [<select> (styling difficult)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#styling_with_css).

The only work around would be to build or use an existing custom built utility replicating the select and option capability, and that is definitely not simple.

Comment: It is a pity, Many thanks for the feeback :)